# Scraping page with requests doesn't return all html tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape this [page](https://www.skroutz.gr/s/11706397/Guy-Laroche-Linda-Red.html?o=%CE%9C%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%81%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%8D%CE%B6%CE%B9%20Guy%20Laroche%20Linda%20Red) in order to extract the details of each [li] tag inside the [ol id="prices"]. The problem is that the returned .html code has some blank tags. Specifically, in each [li], the content of the tag [div class="shop cf"] is not returned. I have used requests and BeautifulSoup for this as follows:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://www.skroutz.gr/s/11706397/Guy-Laroche-Linda-Red.html"
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers )

# i also tried the following two commands in order to wait for the page to load
#seconds = 10
#page = requests.get(url, time.sleep(seconds), headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

eshops_grid = soup.find("ol", id="prices")
eshops_product = eshops_grid.findAll("li", class_='cf card js-product-card')
for eshop in eshops_product[0:]:
    eshop_name = eshop.find("div", class_="shop-name").text
    print(eshop_name) # I need to print the eshop_name for each eshop
```

Although I need to do this by using requests library, I have also used selenium for this reason but the same problem occurs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# We are opening a browser but not visible
print('- Open a browser but not visible ')
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

url = 'https://www.skroutz.gr/s/11706397/Guy-Laroche-Linda-Red.html?o=%CE%9C%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%81%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%8D%CE%B6%CE%B9%20Guy%20Laroche%20Linda%20Red'
#print('- Get the initial url of brandwatch')
driver.get(url)

page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

eshops_grid = soup.find("ol", id="prices")
eshops_product = eshops_grid.findAll("li", class_='cf card js-product-card')
for eshop in eshops_product[0:]:
    eshop_name = eshop.find("div", class_="shop-name").text
    print(eshop_name) # I need to print the eshop_name for each eshop
```

Is there a way to get all the content of each ["li"] in order to extract and print the 'eshop_name'?

Comment: captcha is playing a big game there

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you wanted.

```
import requests
import demjson
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.skroutz.gr',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome"; v="83"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cookie': '_helmet_couch=eyJzZXNzaW9uX2lkIjoiNjgzNzhmMmNmNjI5OTcxNjI5NzU2ZWNmMTM5MzE5MmIiLCJidWNrZXRfaWQiOiJmNTk1ZGRhYy00ZmVhLTQ5NmYtODNkNS00OWQzODgzMWFhYTAiLCJsYXN0X3NlZW4iOjE1OTEyNjgwNTUsInZvbCI6MSwiX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iOiI1a3Yxb3FKTmhXTCs1YUxzdjYzRFk3TlNXeGs5TlhXYmZhM0UzSmtEL0NBPSJ9--22dfbfe582c0f3a7485e20d9d3932b32fbfb721b',
    'if-none-match': 'W/"e6fb8187391e99a90270c2351f9d17cd"',
}

params = (
    ('o', '\u039C\u03C0\u03BF\u03C5\u03C1\u03BD\u03BF\u03CD\u03B6\u03B9 Guy Laroche Linda Red'),
)

response = requests.get('https://www.skroutz.gr/s/11706397/Guy-Laroche-Linda-Red.html', headers=headers, params=params)

data = bs(response.text,'lxml')
s = data.find_all('script')[5].text.split('SKR.page.first_shop_name = ')[1].split(';')[0].replace('"','')
print(s)
```

The Output is:

```
Spitishop
```

Comment: Your code scrapes all the product titles with eshop.find("h3").text. But I need to scrape the specific "div" ( eshop.find("div", class_="shop-name").text ) that I show in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proposed solution works only for the first item. The list of shops is provided by a separate POST request sent through JS, which is then rendered separately by the browser.

You can duplicate the POST request to https://www.skroutz.gr/personalization/product_prices.json using the appropriate headers and POST data (which are the product IDs found in the "js-product-link content-placeholder" items from your original request) and the returned values come in JSON format.

**EDIT**:

OK, the information was "hidden" within HTML comments encoded in base64 in the "original" page. The following code works for identifying information needed regarding the shops. The commented out lines can be used to issue the subsequent POST request, in case any further information is needed and which is not present in the base64 encoded string (which I didn't bother to check, to be honest).

```py
import requests
from lxml import html
import simplejson as json
import copy

sess = requests.Session()
sess.head('https://www.skroutz.gr')

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.skroutz.gr',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome"; v="83"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'if-none-match': 'W/"e6fb8187391e99a90270c2351f9d17cd"'
}

params = (('o', '\u039C\u03C0\u03BF\u03C5\u03C1\u03BD\u03BF\u03CD\u03B6\u03B9 Guy Laroche Linda Red'),)

response = sess.get('https://www.skroutz.gr/s/11706397/Guy-Laroche-Linda-Red.html', headers=headers, params=params)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
# hrefs = tree.xpath('//a[@class="js-product-link content-placeholder"]/@href')
# ids = [x.split('/')[-1] for x in hrefs]
# headers2 = copy.deepcopy(headers)
# headers2['content-type'] = 'application/json'
# ret = sess.post('https://www.skroutz.gr/personalization/product_prices.json', data=json.dumps({'product_ids': ids}), headers=headers2)
details = tree.xpath('//script[@type="application/json"]')[0]
# details.text_content() contains the base64 encoded elements within HTML comments
details_b64 = details.text_content()[4:-3] # strip off the html comments
details_d = json.loads(base64.b64decode(details_b64).decode('utf-8')) # based64 decode the string, decode it in utf-8 and parse the resulting json  object
```